# Как сделать редирект?

Tags: редирект, redirect, perl

В скрипте есть строчка(необходима): `print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";`
Соответственно `print "Location: URL\n\n";` исполняться не станет.
Как быть? Нужно при выполнении определенного условия просто средиректить на главную страницу сайта.

Comment: Продумывать/рефакторить код, видимо, чтобы отдача контента была после того, как выявляется условие делать ли редирект или нет.

Алсо, Location само по себе ничего не значит, и смысл приобретает только со статусом 3xx.

Comment: ПОздно рефакторить, т.к. постоянно какие то дописки происходят, пока методом костылей решаю. Когда наконец все будет нравиться клиенту, и выдумать ему уже будет нечего - будет ясна вся схема и сделаю набело.
На сайте несколько разделов меню(html ссылки,1|2|3), один из разделов - ссылка на cgi-скрипт, который выдает сам динамическую страницу соответствующего раздела. Вот при определенном условии нужно что бы он открыл НЕ динамическую страницу 1 раздела, которая физически лежит на сервере.

Answer (score 1):

Яваскриптом можно сделать редирект:

```
document.location.href = 'http://твой-сайт.ru';
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил так:

```
print <<HTML;
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://url">
<a href="http://url">Нажмите, если у Вас не поддерживается автоматический редирект</a>
HTML
exit;
```

Всем спасибо!